# does PDF Td operator is affected by the Graphics State Stack?

Tags: pdf

I'm trying to write a justified paragraph in a PDF with multiple formats (sizes, italics, bold, colors) and to achieve this I could use the Graphics State Stack to avoid repeating text operators, but it seems that the behavior of the Graphics State Stack depends on the PDF reader. Do I have to repeat the text operators every time I want to change text format? or there is a better way to achieve what I need?

I have the following PDF stream to test the Graphics State Stack of PDF:

```
BT
1 0 0 1 56.69 785.19 Tm
0 -12.1 Td
/F1 11 Tf
1.79 Tw
(rzo motáúe issjstózñ x vasreqyxñ ómfzzííh nohé hábúgíoújé úyz túit k wf ñxaóúgsri rcémwewá)Tj
0 -16.5 Td
5.1 Tw
(óaxhkd óáfythra)Tj
q
  /F2bi 10 Tf
  0.835 0.283 0.833 rg
  4.1718 Tw
  (olvéd cjtwymelgv stzr cc uxnugtqúic)Tj
  q
    /F3b 15 Tf
    0.491 0.895 0.74 rg
    15 Tw
    (q hwvúñóál íu vpfíxht)Tj
    0 -16.5 Td
    (qfyébávrx vkámday)Tj
  Q
Q
(cúprnfr úhwñ rá wdwñ óyxáumvpn nmrdó)Tj ET
```

In the Ubuntu PDF reader the `q` operator doesn't affect the `Td` operator.

[image: PDF reader in ubuntu]

In the Chrome PDF reader the `q` operator do affect the `Td` operator.

[image: PDF reader in chrome]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The save and restore graphics state operators are not allowed in text objects, i.e. **q** and **Q** between **BT** and **ET** is invalid.

Thus, your content stream is invalid and the behavior of pdf viewers attempting to display it is undefined.

Comment: It becomes clear in [figure 9 (Graphics Objects)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rKvsi.png) in ISO 32000-1.